# JPA projection query not brining List of fields with other standalone fields

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I already went through many links like : [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns), but here is my model. I am using **Spring Boot 2.0.0**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee{
   @Id
   private Long employeeId;
   ....
   ....
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Department> departments;
   ..
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

I've written project like

```
public class EmployeeDto{
    public Long getEmployeeId();

    public List<Department> getDepartments();
}
```

When I developed JPARepositoryQuery, I get whole object. In fact, I am only expecting EmployeeId and list of departmentIds thats it.

```
@Query("SELECT s.employeeId, s.departments FROM Employee s WHERE s.employeeId = :employeeId")
EmployeeDto findProjectionByEmployeeId(@Param("employeeId") Long employeeId);
```

How can we restrict to get only two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is short: That's not possible.

The result of your query will be a cartesian product with id and all fields of Department.

Answer (score 0):

You  already know `employeeId`, so just get departments

```java
@Query("SELECT empl.departments FROM Employee empl WHERE empl.employeeId = :employeeId")
List<Department> findDepartmentsByEmployeeId(@Param("employeeId") Long employeeId);
```

Comment: I also need to check if EmployeeId exists in DB if yes then I will check if departmentId coming in response is part of employeeId

Comment: What do you want to check? Don't you trust SQL?

Comment: @Pra_A Please log SQL query. This JPQL query is converted to getting departments by foreign key. And looks like you have incorrect mapping with `mappedBy = "departmentId"`. You need something like `mappedBy = "employee"`.

Comment: How can we make sure if EmployeeId and departmentId both exists?

Comment: @Pra_A Better to make an additional query to verify `employeeId`.

Comment: Thanks, can u pls guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770075/spring-boot-two-datasource-configuration-for-h2-db-failed-to-create-tables-and-i?