# Spring Boot Two Datasource configuration for H2 DB failed to create tables and insert data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I am looking to configure the two DS in my Spring Boot application and have followed link - https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7. We've created `application.yml` file.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console


my:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:test2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

Here is the code

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localKEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "localKTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.mastercard.merchantbinding.repository.K")
@EntityScan(basePackages = ENTITY_PACKAGE)
public class LocalKH2DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "localKdataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "localKEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("localKdataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages(ENTITY_PACKAGE).persistenceUnit("LOCAL_K").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "localKTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("localKEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Another

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localSEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "localSTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.mastercard.merchantbinding.repository.S")
@EntityScan(basePackages = ENTITY_PACKAGE)
public class LocalSH2DataSourceConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "localSdataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "localSEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("localSdataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages(ENTITY_PACKAGE).persistenceUnit("LOCAL_S").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "localSTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("localSEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Error -

```
Table TRAN_DATA not found; SQL statement: --insert into ABC ------- [42S02-60]
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct, however the reason why auto-ddl is not working has to do with the fact that you are manually creating the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, during the creation of your datasources.

You can mitigate this by instructing each bean to perform the DDL operation manually like:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.foo.springtest.users.models")
        .persistenceUnit("user")
        .properties(properties)
        .build();
}
```

Notice the following two lines that instruct hibernate to run DDL:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
```